# Laravel dry run on eloquent save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Is there any way to execute a dry run in Laravel when saving?

Lets say I have 2 models, `Booking` and `BookingDetails`. I do not want either one of them to save without the other.

At the moment I'm filling an saving like this:

```
 // Create new booking

  try
  {
       $booking = with(new Booking)->fill(request()->all())->save();
       $bookingDetails = with(new BookingDetails)->fill(request()->all())->save();
  }
  catch (\Exception $e)
  {
       // Die quietly
  }
```

Ideally I want to be able to check the booking save is going to work first, because if the booking save doesn't work, I don't want to save the details. Then if the details can't save, I don't want to save the booking in the first place, I just want to throw an error and save **nothing** if either fail.

Is there any way I can dry run and test all of the saves work, and if they do and they're all OK, save for real? Instead of doing something like this

```
 // Create new booking

  try
  {
       $booking = with(new Booking)->fill(request()->all())->save();
       try
       {
           $bookingDetails = with(new BookingDetails)->fill(request()->all())->save();
       }
       catch (\Exception $ex)
       {
            // Find the booking here and delete, because the details cant be saved
       }
  }
  catch(\Exception $e)
  {
       // Die quietly
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DB Transaction](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions) is what you are looking for.

DB transaction only save `booking` and `bookingDetails` when both of them are good. If either of them fails, nothing is saved.

```
DB::transaction(function () {
       $booking = with(new Booking)->fill(request()->all())->save();
       $bookingDetails = with(new BookingDetails)->fill(request()->all())->save();
}, 5);
```

Comment: Yep @S_R this is accurate. A transaction will rollback all the changes if any of the queries throws an error. So it will only persist the data when **every sentence ** is successfully executed,

Comment: So does this work on any database function? Store, update and delete? All I have to do is wrap them inside the transaction function?

Comment: @S_R yes, you are correct. Put everything you want in a transaction.

Comment: How would I catch an exception using this method? Can `DB::transaction` be placed straight inside a try catch?

Comment: @MichaelNguyen Also, I cant seem to find in the documentation what the `5` is that you have passed in after the callback, what is this?

Comment: @S_R the `5` is the number of times Laravel will try until it gives up. Go (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database) and scroll down to `Handling deadlocks`. Also, if you want to handle exception, you need to handle transaction manually with `DB::beginTransaction();` `DB::rollBack();` and `DB::commit();` See the `Manually Using Transactions` section in the same link.